# Why isn't my "Launchpad Registration" accomplishment showing up?

Tags: accomplishments

I registered to Launchpad about a year ago, but I haven't got the trophy. Do I have to do something more? It's been a few days since I started using Ubuntu Accomplishments. And how does the verification work? Do i get a verification email or something?

Comment: I made  Ask Ubuntu account half an hour ago and I havent got the trophy for this either. I did add my Ask Ubuntu address to Ubuntu accomplishments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up Ubuntu One. The accomplishment app uses your Ubuntu One account to verify your accomplishments.

Comment: Now I installed Ubuntu One. Haven't got trophies yet, but i guess it takes some time

Comment: restarted computer and now it shows my missing trophies

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the Launchpad email?

[image]

Comment: yes I did. It does not seem to bee the problem

Comment: since you just install it, please wait until they verify your registration.

Comment: okei, i will wait a bit more then

Comment: I noticed that there already were those missing trophy files in my computer. I restarted my computer and now Ubuntu Accomplishments shows my missing trophies :)

Comment: happy ubuntu sir